# Can't figure out how to properly use CASE WHEN statement in a ORDER BY clause

Tags: sql, postgresql, case-when

I get an error on pgadmin query tool saying that deelnemers (it's a dutch database) doesn't exist. However as far as I understand sql queries the SELECT should be executed before the ORDER BY.

I have already tried changing the order of the CASE WHEN statement but I keep getting this error.

```
SELECT r.reisnr , COUNT (k.naam) AS deelnemers
FROM ruimtereizen.reizen r
INNER JOIN ruimtereizen.deelnames d
USING (reisnr)
INNER JOIN ruimtereizen.klanten k
USING (klantnr)
GROUP BY r.reisnr
ORDER BY CASE WHEN COUNT (DISTINCT deelnemers) > 1 THEN deelnemers
WHEN COUNT (DISTINCT deelnemers) = 1 THEN r.reisnr
ELSE deelnemers
END
```

The error is that deelnemers doesn't exist.

Comment: Please explain what you are trying to do.  The query doesn't make sense.

Comment: "deelnemers" doesn't exist except as an alias for "COUNT (k.naam)".  Think of an alias as ONLY being a column heading and not an actual field in your database.  Since it only ever exists as part of the final output of your query, you can't use it within your query.  What you would have to is use "COUNT (k.naam)" in your CASE statement instead of "deelnemers".  Even then I'm not 100% confident that you can use the "COUNT (DISTINCT COUNT (k.naam)) " in your Order By.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a general answer I would say your "generic SQL" is good. But... every database supports some features and fails to support other ones.

Anyway, to be on the safe side I would pre-compute your `COUNT()` function in a CTE so I could use it freely on the outer query. For example:

```
with
x as (
  SELECT 
    r.reisnr, 
    COUNT (k.naam) AS deelnemers,
    COUNT (DISTINCT deelnemers) as dd
  FROM ruimtereizen.reizen r
  INNER JOIN ruimtereizen.deelnames d
  USING (reisnr)
  INNER JOIN ruimtereizen.klanten k
  USING (klantnr)
  GROUP BY r.reisnr
)
select * 
from x
ORDER BY CASE WHEN dd > 1 THEN deelnemers
              WHEN dd = 1 THEN reisnr
              ELSE deelnemers
              END
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `CASE` with `ORDER BY` is simple.  The expression simply needs to be valid.

I can only imagine what you want to do.  If you want to order first by `deelnemers` and then by the name, you don't need `CASE`:

```
order by deelnemeers desc, reisnr
```